# how to use subclipse with eclipse kepler on ubuntu 14.04 x64?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, svn, subclipse

This is guide I'm trying to following
http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL
 but my code isn't working.

Errors:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = -/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so
```

SVN version

> SVN version 1.8.8 (r1568071) compiled Aug 13 2014, 17:12:39 on
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

```
vinicius@ubuntu:~$ sudo find / -name libsvnjavahl-1.so

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so
```

My eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.library.path=-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so
```

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769989/failed-to-load-javahl-library

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

-Djava.library.path=-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so

It should be:

-Djava.library.path=-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni

Comment: /etc/eclipse.ini (Ubuntu 14.04)